# How to write the regex for matching a price on a page?

Tags: php, regex

Hello I am trying to get the price for products from different URLS and I know how to get the content but I suck at writing the regex functions, can someone please help me write one. It should match any number after a $, so for example "$40" "$40.95" and "$ 45"

Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend a tutorial on how to use regex, such as [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '
    Hi! This answer will cost you $10. 
    If you do not vote this answer up, it will cost you another in $1.23 or $ 2.45. 
    Be good and transfer me arround $12.45 bucks to my IBAN SI56 1234 4567 8901 234.
    Just joking, it is for free ;-)
';
preg_match_all('~(\$\h?\d+(\.\d+)?)~', $string, $matches);

echo "<pre>".print_r($matches[1],true)."</pre>";
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => $10
    [1] => $1.23
    [2] => $ 2.45
    [3] => $12.45
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
/(\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)/
```

Comment: The second part of your regex should be (\.([0-9]{2})?)

Comment: and if you sometimes have a space between $ and 45 then you'll need \$\s?[0-9]+

Comment: @ScottFeingold: What if number is rounded to 4 decimals?

Comment: Because he is looking for prices in American Dollars, they will either have no decimal place or 2 decimal places. It is very uncommon to find anything else and by including just the '+' it is possible to end up with unwanted matches. But I believe that choice is up to the coder to decide how strict they want the data set to be. The should choose if they want to include possible unwanted matches or exclude possible matches.

Comment: @Scott: '+' will not end up with unwanted matches, because '+' means one or more of [0-9]. So if the price is $0.1234 or $0.12 it should be fetched. But yes, this is up to the coder to decide. I personally would fetch full number, and then cut it if a needed to...